# Store Java enums in Postgresql and Hibernate 6 using hbm.xml

Tags: java, hibernate, enums, hibernate-types

I am unable to figure out how to store a Java Enum using a Postgresql Enum Type with Hibernate 6 and the legacy hbm.xml.

With Hibernate 5, I used to use the `hiberate-types` project with following XML:

```
<property name="type" column="Type" access="field">
        <type name="com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.basic.PostgreSQLEnumType">
            <param name="enumClass">"my-java-enum-type"</param>
            <param name="useNamed">true</param>
        </type>
    </property>
```

But, this is not working with Hibernate 6 anymore. There is a documentation from the package's Author how to use it with annotations, but currently it is not feasible for us to switch to annotations (https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-an-enum-type-with-jpa-and-hibernate/).

I would be glad if anyone could give a hint.

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not working"? Can you post the exception that you get or clarify a bit what happens?

Comment: I was getting an exception that no mapping was found for Type.OTHER (1111).

Comment: Please create an issue in the issue tracker(https://hibernate.atlassian.net) with a test case(https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/blob/master/orm/hibernate-orm-5/src/test/java/org/hibernate/bugs/JPAUnitTestCase.java) that reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by writing my own type:

```
public class PersistentEnum<T extends Enum<T>> extends EnumType<T>
{
    @Override
    public  void
            nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement preparedStatement, T obj, int index, SharedSessionContractImplementor session)    throws HibernateException,
                                                                                                                            SQLException
    {
        if(obj == null)
        {
            preparedStatement.setNull(index, java.sql.Types.OTHER);
        }
        else
        {
            preparedStatement.setObject(index, obj.toString(), java.sql.Types.OTHER);
        }

    }
}
```

With this, the former posted hbm.xml code is working.